The Problem of Schoenmakers PVSS Secret Recovery
In Schoenmakers PVSS, we are using the Lagrange interpolating polynomial to recover a secret, but when I plug in an example for calculation, I find that the secret cannot be recovered:
$$
h^s=\prod_{i=1}^tS_i^{\lambda_i} \quad (\bmod\ p)\\ 
S_i=Y_i^{(x_i^{-1} \bmod q)}\ \ \ (= h^{f(i)})\quad(\bmod\ p)\\
\lambda_i=\prod_{j=1,j\neq i}^{t-1}(\frac {j}{j-i})\quad (\bmod\ q)
$$
Here are my example:
$$
p = 23，q=11，h = 3，g = 2，(t,\ n) = (3,\ 4)\\
f(x) = 2+3x+2x^2\quad (\bmod\ 11)\\
s = 2，secret\ S =3^2= 9\\\ \\
P_1:\quad x_1=3,\ \ y_1=27\bmod 23=4\\
P_2:\quad x_2=5,\ \ y_2=243\bmod 23=13\\
P_3:\quad x_3=9,\ \ y_3=18\\
P_4:\quad x_4=2,\ \ y_4=9\\\ \\
f(1) = 7,\ f(2) = 5,\ f(3) = 7,\ f(4) = 2 \\
Y_1 =4^7\bmod 23=8,\ Y_2 =4,\ Y_3 = 6,\ Y_4 =12\\\ \\
x_1^{-1}=4,\ x_2^{-1}=9,\ x_3^{-1}=5,\ x_4^{-1}=6\\
S_1 = 8^4\bmod23=2,\ S_2=13,\ S_3=2,\ S_4=9\\\ \\
choose\ P_1(1,2),\ P_2(2,13),\ P_3(3,2)\\
\lambda_1=2,\ \lambda_2=10,\ \lambda_3=1\\
\prod_{i=1}^tS_i^{\lambda_i} =2^{13}\times13^{10}\times2^1\ \bmod 23\\=13\neq9
$$
What's Wrong?

Why are you considering two different primes $p$ and $q$? Doesn't the original publication require to have the participants' public key in the same field?
